# Why is my expected JSON literal 'null', and how do I fix it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, .net-core

I am currently working on building an API-powered back-end using .Net Core with Windows Authentication. Attempting to POST data to this backend results in a 400 error :

`"'noticeNumber=Hello%2C%20world!' is an invalid JSON literal. Expected the literal 'null'. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 1."`

The API is currently set up to receive an object containing data on a receipt. One of the properties of this object is an ID for notices generated in other apps. This, and all other properties, are nullable :

```cs
// Receipts Controller.


[ApiController]
[Route("receipts")]
public class ReceiptsController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost("post_insertReceipt")]
    public Task<IActionResult> InsertReceipt(ReceiptForm receipt) {
       try {/* ... */}
       catch { /* ... */ } 
    }
}

//Receipt Form VM

public class ReceiptForm
{

    public string? NoticeNumber { get; set; }

    /*... */
}
```

The Javascript & jQuery used to call the API look like this :

```js
var data2 = {
    noticeNumber: "Hello, world!"
}

$.ajax({
    url: "https://localhost:portNumber/receipts/post_insertReceipt",
    type: "POST",
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
    },
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: data2,
    success: function(data) { /* Display success alert */ },
    error: function(xhr) { /* display error alert */ }
})
```

As far as I understand, the syntax for the data object is correct, but something clearly disagrees. I have attempted to post null as data, only to get an error for for having posted any data.

So then, why is the expected literal 'null'? What determines the expected literal, why, and how do I fix this issue?

Comment: Can't remember off the top of my head, but shouldn't the data parameter be `data: JSON.stringify(data2)`?

Answer (score 0):

@DavidG's comment on the main post reveals my mistake. APIs communicate with objects that have been serialized into JSON strings.

My prior experience with non-API-based MVC had led me to to conclude that I could just pass the Javascript object into the `$.ajax`'s data field as can be done - that is **not** the case.

Data must be parsed into a serialized JSON string with `JSON.Stringify()` in order to be processed by the API properly.

```js
$.ajax({
    url: "https://localhost:portNumber/receipts/post_insertReceipt",
    type: "POST",
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
    },
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: JSON.stringify(data2),
    success: function(data) { /* Display success alert */ },
    error: function(xhr) { /* display error alert */ }
})
```

Comment: You should really let the person who did the comment write the answer so they can get credit for it.

Comment: **Note:** you only need to pass stringified data *if* you specify that your content type is stringified data - the "easier" fix would be to remove `contentType: "application/json",`

Comment: Your second paragraph is **not true**. You **can** pass a javascript object as the `data` field. However, by default the object will be serialised as **urlencoded** form data, not JSON. Notice that the data you receive on your server is `noticeNumber=Hello%2C%20world!` which is **correct** format as would be submitted by a HTML form. Basically the default behavior supports non-API based MVC usage instead of your non-standard (though nowdays very common) use of JSON